# How to write request in Jmeter to test SignalR hub

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr, jmeter-plugins

I have very simple method in my SignalR hub:

```
public class ActivityHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task NewMessage(string username, string message) =>
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", username, message);
    }
```

It works perfectly when I use my client (also very simple application written in JavaScript)

The clue of my question is to find how to test my hub via Jmeter. I found already some topics on stackoverflow, and well tutorial:
https://medium.com/@goldberg_rui/test-signalr-performance-with-jmeter-59083554f917
I wrote simple test, but it doesn't works. I used `“ WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch”` as in tutorial.

Firstly I negotiate (`simple HTTP Request`):
`http://localhost:56325/activity/negotiate` that returns me some data I extract connectionId from.

Then I open new connection (`WebSocket Open Connection`) with `/activity?id=$(ConnectionId)`.

On the end I trying to invoke method (`WebSocket Single Write Sampler`) in my hub with existing connection, and I put data: `{"arguments": ["abc","abc"], "invocationId":123,"target":"NewMessage","type":4}`. Unfortuantely i getting errors with message:

```
Response code:Sampler error
Response message:Sampler configured for using existing connection, but there is no connection
```

Where Is bug in my test? I know that I need to add terminating character `0x1E` at the end of the message what I have done. Maybe type of message (4) is not proper or arguments are wrongly paassed?
I also put screenshots of my JMeter test.
Important: Only second writer is enabled, the first one is disabled.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found.
Change RegEx Extractor to JSON Extractor and set `Json Path Expression` as `$.connectionId`.

The rest of test was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup looks good, however the error message means that the connection is not open so my expectation is that your `WebSocket Open Connection` sampler fails somewhere somehow.

1. Use [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to inspect request and response and compare them with the ones sent by JavaScript
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries as looking into yellow exclamation sign at upper right corner of your JMeter GUI it looks like there are at least 2 errors which need to be fixed. You can also consider [increasing JMeter debug logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the websocket samplers by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change