# How to register Jmeter sampler in SignalR server as client

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I need to test my SignalR server, to be more strict i need to test that hub and method:

```
 public class ActivityHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task NewMessage(string username, string message) =>
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", username, message);
    }
```

I need to "bind" my test as listener. I would like to do it via JMeter and it should works like my js client which is bound as listener and can listen in method:

```
connection.on('ReceiveMessage', (user, message) => {
    console.log(`${user} got message from server: ${message}`);
});
```

I found nice tests and example of controller in SignalR:
https://github.com/ruirafael01/SignalRJmeter
But there we are testing only methods like:

```
public async Task<SignalRInfo> NormalHUBMethod(string inputString)
        {
            var signalRInfo = new SignalRInfo(GenerateValidGuidForInfo(), $"Message received on SignalRHub: {inputString}", DateTime.Now);
            _listOfInformationMessages.Add(signalRInfo);

            return signalRInfo;
        }
```

I using  “ WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch” plugin. The scaffolding of my test is precisely described in topic: [How to write request in Jmeter to test SignalR hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436426/how-to-write-request-in-jmeter-to-test-signalr-hub)

Answer (score 0):

Due to my knowledge it's not possible. The best workaround I developed is to make method like:

```
 public async Task<DtoMessage> NewMessage(string username, string message)
        {
            var dto = new DtoMessage() { Message = message, Username = username };
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", dto);
            return dto;
        }
```

and properly change the client to receive the data. But I still have some troubles with test in JMeter.